# Energy Consumption of individual buildings

Tags: data-request, city, energy

We are testing academic algorithms on energy consumption.

I am looking for a **Energy per building** dataset. Is there any city that open such kind of data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Electricity and (space) heating load curves for a city](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/electricity-and-space-heating-load-curves-for-a-city)

Comment: I know that NASA/GSFC has data on energy consumption for its buildings  (I saw the graphs at the IRAD poster session a couple of weeks ago).  It's possible that you might be able to get energy usage for other government buildings, as well, as they're all trying to lower energy usage per OPM : http://www.opm.gov/sustainability/

Comment: Are you looking for residential, office, or public building energy use?

Comment: I concur with Phil. Answers to locating datasets for this type of question is well covered at: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/electricity-and-space-heating-load-curves-for-a-city

Comment: @JeanneHolm I am still looking for residential dataset, I think that the problem is entirely related to privacy. Most of them are related to commercial buildings.

Comment: With the new 'smart meters' in a lot of areas (I'm under PEPCO), you might be able to get aggregated data.  data.gov has links via [green button](https://www.data.gov/energy/welcome-green-button), but I don't know if any of them release aggregated data.  (and it'd only be electrical, not oil/propane/gas/etc).

Answer (score 6):

i think open ei has this in their building energy data book:
http://en.openei.org/doe-opendata/dataset/buildings-energy-data-book
here's a section from that which is a survey of building energy consumption and extends past 2011:
http://www.eia.gov/consumption/commercial/data/2012/
lastly, try the data hub for the energy performance of buildings for the eu:
http://www.buildingsdata.eu/

Answer (score 4):

Cornell Univserity offers real-time energy consumption data for individual buildings, and well as generation from renewable or plant generation

**http://portal.emcs.cornell.edu/**

Categories, each having individual links

- Total Campus Energy Demand
- Renewable Energy Generation
- Central Plant Generation
- Building Utility Metering

There are data download options (although writing a script will help the process)

Answer (score 2):

The [Amsterdam Energy Atlas](http://maps.amsterdam.nl/energie_gaselektra/?LANG=en) is an interactive map that shows a building average of electricity and gas consumption per square meter of floor space.

It's not exactly per building and there isn't yet a download option. According to my Dutch translation, they will soon update the data and then make it available.

[image]