# Daily electricity usage dataset

Tags: data-request, energy

Where can I find a dataset of daily electricity usage from a zone or country anywhere in the world?

Anywhere = i accept any dataset from anywhere in the world, but at least a daily usage

Comment: It might be easier to find energy production from power plants in a given area, rather than usage.

Comment: The [GreenButton energy data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5977/1511) may be of interest for smaller consumption zones (ie. buildings)

Comment: There is a growing list of energy consumption/production dashboards at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7377/1511

Answer (score 9):

The European countries in the Entsoe-E provide hourly data aggregated on the country level.

Please see [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3828/1511) for more details.

> European Network of Transmission System Operators for Electricity ([ENTSOE](https://www.entsoe.eu/)) provides Consumption and Production data for individual countries (and Exchange data between countries). ([Link to Data Portal](https://www.entsoe.eu/data/data-portal/Pages/default.aspx).)
>
> Link to [**ENTSOE Consumption data**](https://www.entsoe.eu/data/data-portal/consumption/Pages/default.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Hint: If you want to mimic a city's consumption, take a small country like Luxembourg.

Answer (score 9):

ERDF, France's network operator has put many datasets online this year. If you can read french, that's a great option since they have great visualization too.
website: https://erdf.opendatasoft.com/

**Bilan Électrique au pas journalier:** [Daily consumption and more since August 2010
Visualization](https://erdf.opendatasoft.com/explore/embed/dataset/bilan-electrique-jour/?tab=analyze&sort=date&dataChart=eyJxdWVyaWVzIjpbeyJjb25maWciOnsiZGF0YXNldCI6ImJpbGFuLWVsZWN0cmlxdWUtam91ciIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOnsidGFiIjoiYW5hbHl6ZSIsInNvcnQiOiJkYXRlIn19LCJjaGFydHMiOlt7InR5cGUiOiJsaW5lIiwiZnVuYyI6IkFWRyIsInlBeGlzIjoiY29uc29tbWF0aW9uIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjNjZjMmE1In1dLCJ4QXhpcyI6ImRhdGUiLCJtYXhwb2ludHMiOiIiLCJ0aW1lc2NhbGUiOiJkYXkiLCJzb3J0IjoiIn1dLCJ0aW1lc2NhbGUiOiJ5ZWFyIn0%3D&static=false&datasetcard=false)

**Data:** Bilan Électrique au pas demi-heure: 30 min intervals consumption and more since August 2010 - **[LINK](https://erdf.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/bilan-electrique-demi-heure/?tab=table&sort=horodate&dataChart=eyJxdWVyaWVzIjpbeyJjb25maWciOnsiZGF0YXNldCI6ImJpbGFuLWVsZWN0cmlxdWUtZGVtaS1oZXVyZSIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOnsidGFiIjoiYW5hbHl6ZSIsInNvcnQiOiJob3JvZGF0ZSJ9fSwiY2hhcnRzIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoibGluZSIsImZ1bmMiOiJBVkciLCJ5QXhpcyI6ImluamVjdGlvbl9kZV9ydGUiLCJjb2xvciI6IiM2NmMyYTUifV0sInhBeGlzIjoiaG9yb2RhdGUiLCJtYXhwb2ludHMiOiIiLCJ0aW1lc2NhbGUiOiJob3VyIiwic29ydCI6IiJ9XSwidGltZXNjYWxlIjoieWVhciJ9)**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try this UC Machine Learning Dataset

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Individual+household+electric+power+consumption#

UW has similar dataset. Their page says they will posts the datasets soon. You may want to contact them to get a copy beforehand.

http://ubicomplab.cs.washington.edu/projects/datasets

The Australian government's Department of Industry has a dataset on 31 example homes in 30 minute intervals on their open data site:

http://data.gov.au/dataset/sample-household-electricity-time-of-use-data

University of Massachusetts Amherst also has a research dataset:

http://traces.cs.umass.edu/index.php/Smart/Smart

Answer (score 5):

The Australian government has published a Smart-Grid Smart-City Customer Trial Data.

There are two datasets (with additional bits and pieces - see below):

- One contains consumptions of 30 families measured very half hour over one year.
- The other list similar data for 3,000 families

See [smart-grid-smart-city-customer-trial-data](https://data.gov.au/dataset/smart-grid-smart-city-customer-trial-data)

> This data is from the customer trial conducted as part of the Smart
>   Grid Smart City (SGSC) project (2010-2014).  It provides one of the
>   few linked sets of customer time of use (half hour increments) and
>   demographic data for Australia, as well as detailed information on
>   appliance use, climate, retail and distributor product offers, and
>   other related factors. The project was jointly funded by the
>   Australian Government and an industry consortia, led by Ausgrid. Data
>   resources that comprise this Customer Trial Data may be linked by the
>   Customer ID number. Details of data resources for this dataset are
>   listed below and include: electricity use interval readings; customer
>   household data; home area network plug readings; peak events; peak
>   events response; and offer and acceptance.

Answer (score 5):

[The Almanac of Minutely Power dataset Version 2](http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201637) captures three major types of energy consumption, namely electricity, water, and gas.

The data were captured in a Canadian residential home over a 2-year period (1 minute intervals). Also, it has been beautifully cleaned and ready to be analyzed.