# Examples of (near) real-time energy dashboards or portals

Tags: data-request, energy, real-time

What are some examples of real-time or live data dashboards related to consumption, production or transmission of energy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Energy: Real-time data portals and dashboards

(*community wiki*)

**Cities**

- [Hamburg](http://www.energieportal-hamburg.de/distribution/energieportal/energyclock/EnergyClock.action?locale=en) - Feed-in from wind and solar energy into the Hamburg electricity grid

---

**State/Region**

- [Ontario gridwatch](http://live.gridwatch.ca/home-page.html)

---

**Countries**

- U.S. Electric System Operating Data ([see below](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9321/1511))
- Switzerland - [Swissgrid wide area monitoring](https://www.swissgrid.ch/swissgrid/en/home/reliability/wam.html)
- Sweden (and neigbhors) - [The Control Room](http://www.svk.se/en/national-grid/the-control-room/)
- [Denmark Energinet](http://www.energinet.dk/Flash/Forside/UK/index.html) (requires Flash)
- [Great Britain Gridwatch](http://gridwatch.templar.co.uk/)
- [Spain](https://demanda.ree.es/demandaEng.html) - real time production and demand (flash) - and super [dataviz](http://energia.ningunaparte.net/en/)
- [Winderful](https://winderful.diascreative.net/) - UK wind energy
- Ireland [EirGrid SmartGrid](http://smartgriddashboard.eirgrid.com/)
- [France Gridwatch](http://gridwatch.templar.co.uk/france/) (direct [CSV](http://gridwatch.templar.co.uk/downloads/french-grid.csv) download)
- Australia - [Live photovoltaic performance](http://pv-map.apvi.org.au/live)

---

**Multi-country**

- [ENTSO-E Transparency - Cross-border flows](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/) - European organization of transmission service operators (TSOs)
- [EEX Transparency](https://www.eex-transparency.com) (mostly production availability and forecasts, to avoid market manipulation - example [Actual Production, Germany](https://www.eex-transparency.com/homepage/power/germany/production/usage/actual-production-100-mw-))
- European Grid Frequency - [Wide Area Monitoring](https://www.swissgrid.ch/swissgrid/en/home/reliability/wam.html)

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: care for more real-time/not energy portals here? i realize that deviates from question, i just like the idea of the wiki and how well you curate these...

Comment: I'd like to focus this question on energy, but feel free to open another and create a community wiki answer. maybe a theme would be "real-time", where as many of these energy portals have a 1 day lag.

Answer (score 3):

Just released (2016, as Beta):

**[U.S. Electric System Operating Data](http://www.eia.gov/beta/realtime_grid/#/summary/demand)**

US-wide energy demand (actual and forecast) at hourly intervals, plus more

User Guide ([PDF](http://www.eia.gov/beta/realtime_grid/docs/UserGuideAndKnownIssues.pdf))

[image]