# Realtime Power Outages Global/North America

Tags: data-request, energy, real-time

Does anyone have, or know of, any sort of real-time source of power outages globally? Or at least in North America. Everywhere I can find is just a local power company or proprietary.

Either a Compiled Map or API would be fine.

Comment: Did you see these answers? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7377/1511
(BTW - local power companies often don't know about small-scale outages at the [distribution transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_transformer) level, until the customers report them)

Comment: I closed this because OP didn't reply to comment, and also the way the question is worded, it's impossible to answer - (there is no global transmission grid, and outages are often small scale, so it makes no sense to have a global- or large-scale dataset in real-time for small, local outages). OP - please update your question to re-open.