# Smart Grid Smart City -- Customer trial data

Tags: data-request, energy

I am looking for the Smart Grid Smart City (SGSC) customer trial data set. The data set was mentioned, and linked to, in [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7685/10671) to [this question.](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4609/daily-electricity-usage-dataset)

I have made an account at the following [site](http://data.gov.au/dataset/smart-grid-smart-city-customer-trial-data) in an attempt to access the data, but I get a message that I am

> Unauthorised to read package smart-grid-smart-city-customer-trial-data

For completeness, I *was* able to access other data sets at the http://data.gov.au/dataset/ website, just not the SGSC data that I am seeking to access.

For those interested, more information on the data set can be found [here.](https://researchdata.ands.org.au/smart-grid-smart-customer-trial/644597)

Answer (score 5):

The dataset has been made unavailable for public access due to some privacy concerns (customers re-identification). Until the risk of re-identification has been removed, it won't be available.

Comment: Has the status changed?

Comment: AFAIK, it's still unavailable :(