# Water & Energy Usage Data

Tags: data-request, energy

Is anyone aware of where I can obtain hourly water & energy usage/consumption data or data related to water industries (can be anywhere in the world).

Comment: Related: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/electricity-and-space-heating-load-curves-for-a-city